# Interrupt takes longer than expected

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, timers

I am trying to write a delay function in C, which should take 0.5 seonds then carry on. I am aware that there are libraries for this purpouse, I want to make it myself.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#define bitset(var,bitno) ((var) |= (1 << (bitno)))

int volatile time_unit;

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {

  time_unit += 1;
}

void wait_func(){
  TCNT0 = 0;
  time_unit = 0;
  while (time_unit < 31);
}


int main(void){
  DDRD = 1;
   cli();
  bitset(TCCR0A, WGM01);
  bitset(TCCR0B, CS00);
  bitset(TCCR0B, CS02);
  OCR0A = 0xFF;
  bitset(TIMSK0, OCIE0A);
  sei();

  while(1){
    PIND = 0;
    wait_func();
    PIND = 1;
    wait_func();
  };
}
```

The timer is in CTC- Mode 1024 prescaler, counting 31*255 (OCR0A = 0xFF) times should give about 0.5 seconds at a base clockrate of 16MHz of the Arduino Atmega328p. The code works, but it turns the LED on and of at a rate of 1 second, (1 sec on 1 sec off). I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `PIND = 1;` toggles the state of bit 0 of `PORTD`.
- `PIND = 0;` does nothing at all; no toggling of any pins.

So you're simply just not toggling as often as you think.  Your delay itself is otherwise fine.  Change `PIND = 0;` to  `PIND = 1;` and it will work as expected.  Having done that you can get rid of one set of `PIND = 1;` and `wait_func();` call.

Alternately, if you want to follow the current form of the code, set and clear the bit on `PORTD` directly:

```c
while(1){
  PORTD &= ~1; // or &= 0xFE
  wait_func();
  PORTD |=  1; 
  wait_func();
}
```

For what it's worth:

- The semicolon after your while loop does nothing.
- The `time_unit` should probably be an `unsigned char` / `uint8_t`.
- Unless you're running really tight on code space, it's probably best not to rely on the prior state of the timer hardware registers.

Comment: Sorry for the maybe trivial question but I always thought that PIND=1 loads the bit 0b00000001 to register PIND , why does it toggle?

Comment: That's just how the AVR GPIO registers are designed.  It allows for a single write to flip a bit rather than doing a set of read, modify, and write instructions.  `PIND`'s naming in in the spirit of reading from the port.

Comment: Is this true for every GPIO register?

Comment: I think yes, if I understand what you're asking.  For the other GPIO ports on the ATMege328P, writng a  `1` in a `PINx` bit index causes the bit at that same index to toggle in the associated `PORTx` register.  Many (not all) other AVR parts follow this same scheme for their ports.

Comment: See Page 60 in [the ATMega328P datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf).